# How to save device in Cognito?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk

I am new in AWS Cognito and I have a problem with saving Device for user.
In my User pool under Sign-in experience there are:

1. Multi-factor authentication:

   - MFA enforcment: Require MFA
   - MFA methods: Authenticator apps.
2. Device trackig:

   - Remember user devices: Always remember
   - Trust remembered devices to suppress MFA: Yes

I singup and log in using Hosted UI, but no device is displayed in user details.
I tried to do it with code - I created .net console application, it looks like:

```
internal class Program
{
    private const string ClientId = "my_client_id";
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await LoginUser();
    }

    static async Task LoginUser()
    {
        string email = "myEmail";
        string password = "myPassword";

        var authRequest = new InitiateAuthRequest
        {
            AuthFlow = AuthFlowType.USER_PASSWORD_AUTH,
            ClientId = ClientId,
            AuthParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "USERNAME", email },
                { "PASSWORD", password},
            }
        };

        var authResponse = await cognitoClient.InitiateAuthAsync(authRequest);
        if (authResponse.ChallengeName == ChallengeNameType.SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA)
        {
            await SetupSoftwareTokenMFA(authResponse.Session, email, authResponse.ChallengeName);
        }
    }

    static async Task SetupSoftwareTokenMFA(string session, string userName, string challengeName)
    {
        string mfaCode = "myMfaCode";
        var confirmMfaRequest = new RespondToAuthChallengeRequest
        {
              ClientId = ClientId,
              ChallengeName = challengeName,
              Session = session,
              ChallengeResponses = new Dictionary<string, string>
              {
                  { "USERNAME", userName },
                  { "SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA_CODE", mfaCode }
              }
       };

       var confirmMfaResponse = await cognitoClient.RespondToAuthChallengeAsync(confirmMfaRequest);
       await SaveDeviceInformation(confirmMfaResponse.AuthenticationResult, userName);
    }

    static async Task SaveDeviceInformation(AuthenticationResultType result, string userName)
    {
        byte[] randomPasswordBytes = GenerateRandomBytes(40);
        string randomPasswordBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(randomPasswordBytes);

        var deviceSecretVerifierConfig = GenerateDeviceVerifier(result.NewDeviceMetadata.DeviceGroupKey, randomPasswordBase64, userName);

        var confirmDeviceRequest = new ConfirmDeviceRequest
        {
            AccessToken = result.AccessToken,
            DeviceKey = result.NewDeviceMetadata.DeviceKey,
            DeviceName = result.NewDeviceMetadata.DeviceGroupKey,
            DeviceSecretVerifierConfig = deviceSecretVerifierConfig
        };

        var response = await cognitoClient.ConfirmDeviceAsync(confirmDeviceRequest );
    }

    //helper methods, mostly from here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net-extensions-cognito/blob/master/src/Amazon.Extensions.CognitoAuthentication/Util/AuthenticationHelper.cs
    private static byte[] GenerateRandomBytes(int lenght)
    {
        byte[] randomBytes = new byte[lenght];
        using (var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            rng.GetBytes(randomBytes);
        }

        return randomBytes;
    }

    public static DeviceSecretVerifierConfigType GenerateDeviceVerifier(string deviceGroupKey, string devicePass, string username)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        byte[] userIdContent = CognitoAuthHelper.CombineBytes(
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(deviceGroupKey),
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username),
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(":"),
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(devicePass)
        );

        byte[] userIdHash = CognitoAuthHelper.Sha256.ComputeHash(userIdContent);

        byte[] saltBytes = new byte[16];
        RandomNumberGenerator.Create().GetBytes(saltBytes);
        // setting the initial byte to 0-127 to avoid negative salt or password verifier error
        saltBytes[0] = (byte)r.Next(sbyte.MaxValue);

        byte[] xBytes = CognitoAuthHelper.CombineBytes(saltBytes, userIdHash);
        byte[] xDigest = CognitoAuthHelper.Sha256.ComputeHash(xBytes);
        BigInteger x = BigIntegerExtensions.FromUnsignedBigEndian(xDigest);

        var v = BigInteger.ModPow(g, x, N);
        byte[] vBytes = v.ToBigEndianByteArray();

        return new DeviceSecretVerifierConfigType
        {
            PasswordVerifier = Convert.ToBase64String(vBytes),
            Salt = Convert.ToBase64String(saltBytes)
        };
    }

    internal static byte[] CombineBytes(params byte[][] values)
    {
        int combinedLength = 0;
        byte[] returnBytes;
        int copyIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            combinedLength += values[i].Length;
        }

        returnBytes = new byte[combinedLength];

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            Buffer.BlockCopy(values[i], 0, returnBytes, copyIndex, values[i].Length);
            copyIndex += values[i].Length;
        }

        return returnBytes;
    }

    public static BigInteger FromUnsignedBigEndian(byte[] bytes)
    {
        var reverse = bytes.Reverse();

        //Need to end with a zero byte to force positive
        var ensurePos = new byte[reverse.Length + 1];
        Array.Copy(reverse, ensurePos, reverse.Length);

        return new BigInteger(ensurePos);
    }
}
```

And in response I got error: Invalid device key given.

I spend a lot of time on it and cannot figure it out. I found that I need to use `AuthFlow = AuthFlowType.USER_SRP_AUTH` but when I used it it was even worse - I couldn't even authenticate.

Do anyone know how to resolve it?

Comment: This is too much code.  Consider providing a *minimal* reproducible example

Comment: I removed errors handling and getting valus from user - they are hardcoded now. There is still some code, but I believie it is mnimal what I need to do to see problem